# How can I hide certain services (like Facebook) in Filepicker.io?

Tags: filepicker.io

I'm building a business app and having Facebook, etc in the file dialog is not so cool. How can I hide it? I thought it might be possible with custom CSS and a "visibility: hidden" style , but the services don't have individual class names. Only other way is with nth child, but that would be very messy...

Thanks,
Graeme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify it as an option:

```
filepicker.pick({services: ['DROPBOX','BOX',…]}, ....);
```

https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#pick

or:

```
<input type="filepicker" data-fp-services="BOX,COMPUTER">
```

https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#widgets-pick

Comment: Thanks, this works. I had been looking exclusively at pickAndStore() (https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#pickAndStore) which doesn't mention this explicitly. I also assumed it would be done from the Developer Portal, not on a per-call basis. But that's enough excuses - I should have been able to find this myself :-)